# New AVD takes a picture saves to clipboard

Tags: android, android-camera, windows-xp, clipboard, android-virtual-device

When I create a new Android Virtual Device and run it for the first time in Eclipse, I have noticed that it activates my webcam and takes a picture. This picture is saved to my clipboard.

But I was wondering if this is normal and happens to anyone?

INFO:

`Android Development Toolkit Version: 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534`

`Android 4.0.3 API level 15`
`Running on Windows XP`

EDIT: Tracked it down to what I think is the `SDL_app` process.
Also when I disabled my clipboard and started it up I got this printed to the terminal:

`[2012-01-26 05:12:12 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: camera_device_start_capturing: Device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is unable to save frame to the clipboard: 0`

Comment: Sounds weird... I had a quick look around and couldn't find anyone else having the same issue, but I can't imagine why it would happen. For other people to be able to help more though, you might want to give a bit more information (Android version on emulator and stuff like that)

Comment: I have updated the information above.

Comment: How did you disable your clipboard?