# emulator: ERROR: camera_device_start_capturing: Device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is unable to save frame to the clipboard

Tags: android, android-emulator, camera, android-camera, emulation

When I try to start an Android Virtual Device with camera being attached to my laptop's web cam, I get the following message:

```
emulator: ERROR: camera_device_start_capturing: Device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is unable to save frame to the clipboard: 0
```

Here is my setup:

Android Studio 0.5.9

windows 8.1 Pro

Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro laptop

x86 emulator with intel HAX accelarator (same result with ARM)

Emulating Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2

I tried Windows Compatibility options, and tried to run as administrator, but no luck. I see the camera light briefly turned on and then off right before the error is shown. you can find this comment in the source code generating the error:

```
/*
* At this point we need to grab a frame to properly setup framebuffer, and
* calculate pixel format. The problem is that bitmap information obtained
* from the driver doesn't necessarily match the actual bitmap we're going to
* obtain via capGrabFrame / capEditCopy / GetClipboardData
*/

/* Grab a frame, and post it to the clipboard. Not very effective, but this
* is how capXxx API is operating. */
```

I cannot think of anything else to try. I wonder if this even has a solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012924/android-how-to-use-webcam-in-emulator this might provide a solution?

Comment: I have already followed those instructions. I'm getting a different error message.

Comment: I noticed that when I disable my clipboard I get the same error. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8933429/635160

Comment: @Mazar , Any chance you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find a solution at the time. I started testing with actual devices.